# Dynamic and gapless playlist of videos

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html, video

I would like to show a video on a website made of a dynamic list of smaller videos.
For instance, the video would consist of 10 smaller videos (1, 2, 3, 4...), and each of them could be different (1A, 1B, 1C, 1D... 2A, 2B, 2C... 3A). So the result would be 1C-2B-3F-4A...

As you imagine, pregenerating all possible combinations would involve creating thousands of them so the idea is keeping it dynamic. Any ideas on what's the best tool/language on how to do it?

It is important that there are no gaps between them so they feel as one.

Options I'm considering:
- Preloaded movies on Flash (AS3)
- Preloaded video elements on HTML5 (and some JS)
- Using Youtube's API (to use their bandwidth)
- Any of the above with some speed-aware caching

Comment: I would love to see a solution for gapless playback of HTML5 video but  no luck so far...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest streaming with Flash. No precaching is done, so the data transferred is only the data displayed to the user, it's pretty effective in terms of consumption.

I've played with Flash streaming and what you're trying to do isn't far fetched, nor does it require a lot of work. It can be as simple as giving several [stream.play2() commands](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play2%28%29) with an [APPEND transition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStreamPlayTransitions.html).

If you're new to this, there's a nice introductory article here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/video_playlist.html. Also, the samples can give you a quick start and an idea whether the user experience will live up to your demands.

Comment: But does this mean there is absolutely no jump between videoA and videoB? That is what I want to do. Gapless playback so it feels like a unique video.

Comment: I understand that's what you want, however, there are many variables to consider.Theoretically, yes. The buffers are intertwined and while the first video is played for the last 5 secs, the second video is buffered so it can start seamlessly.

Comment: By the way, the description from the play2 function (my first link) states: `Switches seamlessly between files with multiple bit rates and allows a NetStream to resume when a connection is dropped and reconnected.`

Comment: I've also tried play2 with FMS, and with "playlists" (appending a few videos at the beggining) it works amazingly well (real seamless transitions). Switching arbitrarily from one stream to another while playing proved to be a little less reliable, but still I was very surprised by the results (even though NetStreamPlayOptions and buffertimes need lots of "random" tweaking until you get a decent setting).

Comment: You can also use the even simpler NetStream.play() w/multiple NetStreams/NetConnections to pre-buffer video, by simply pausing the video after issuing play :)

Comment: You could do that, but it's more complicated to do it seamlessly. Also, if you keep a NetStream paused for a while, it will eventually purge the buffer, so you have to switch quickly.
Or maybe I'm just not a good enough programmer to pull it off. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but my playback was triggered by the users. Either way, what solved the problem for me, was the `canplaythrough` event. It might help you:

```
function swapVideos(source, target) {
    target.get(0).play();
    target.bind('canplaythrough', function() {
        target.offset({
            top : videoTop,
            left : videoLeft
        });
        source.offset({
            top : 20080,
            left : 20920
        });
        source.get(0).pause();
        var aux = topVideo;
        topVideo = bottomVideo;
        bottomVideo = aux;

    target.unbind('canplaytrough');
    });
}
```